# I have no idea to express my problem in converting a dataframe to another, please read below to more details. Thank so much

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to convert a dataframe (left) to another (right), but I have no idea to do this task. Briefly, the nearest value in `A` was retained and merged with `B`. Please take your time to help me! Thank you so much!

[The original dataframe and converted dataframe (highlighted background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlkpa.png)

Here is the original data.

```
df1 = data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  TIME = c(-2, -1,  0, 11, 13, 24, 28, 36, -3,  0, 12, 13, 24),
  A = c(30, 50, NA, 80, NA, NA, 30, NA, 20, NA, NA, 80, NA),
  B = c(NA,  NA, 2.0,  NA, 2.5, 2.5,  NA, 1.0,  NA, 1.0, 1.0,  NA, 2.5)
)
```

Comment: What's the logic to get from one data frame to the next?

Comment: The non-blank B’s  become A’s and the A immediately preceding a non-blank B becomes an A. The fact that no explanation was included makes me think this is homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df1 %>% 
  fill(A, .direction = c("down")) %>% # fill missing data in A
  drop_na() %>%
  rename(B = A, A = B) %>% # swap the names of columns A and B
  select(ID, TIME, A, B)  # select the order of columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. It keeps the rows with non-missing values in `B` after filling the values in `A` with the previous value. Then it's a matter of rearranging and renaming the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(A) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  rename(B = A, A = B) %>%
  relocate(B, .after = A)
## A tibble: 7 x 4
#     ID  TIME     A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0   2      50
#2     1    13   2.5    80
#3     1    24   2.5    80
#4     1    36   1      30
#5     2     0   1      20
#6     2    12   1      20
#7     2    24   2.5    80
```

---

### Edit

[TarJae's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539316/i-have-no-idea-to-express-my-problem-in-converting-a-dataframe-to-another-pleas/70539450?noredirect=1#comment124694063_70539450) makes the code above shorter:

```
df1 %>%
  fill(A) %>% 
  select(ID, TIME, A=B, B=A) %>%
  drop_na()
```

Comment: @Rui Barradas: We could make it shorter? `df1 %>% 
  fill(A) %>% 
  select(ID, TIME, A=B, B=A) %>% 
  na.omit()`

Comment: @TarJae Yes, much better. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method how we could do it:

```
# swap A and B
df1[ , c(3,4)]  <- df1[ , c(4,3)]
# fill na with prvious value from above
df1$B <- na.omit(df1$B)[cumsum(!is.na(df1$B))]
# remove NA
df1[complete.cases(df1$A),]
```

```
   ID TIME   A  B
3   1    0 2.0 50
5   1   13 2.5 80
6   1   24 2.5 80
8   1   36 1.0 30
10  2    0 1.0 20
11  2   12 1.0 20
13  2   24 2.5 80
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work using lag function

```
   df1%>%
   mutate(new=lag(A))%>%
   filter(!is.na(new),!(is.na(B)))%>%
   select(-A)
```